# Why ImageView is NOT VISIBLE in Layout?

Tags: android

I want to make an image appears as VISIBLE in the layout by programming it.

This is the **XML file** where I declare the image as GONE for then make it VISIBLE from code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/map"
    tools:context="dis2.widget.MainActivity">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/contactsScrollView"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/linkg"
                android:id="@+id/linkgID" 
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the MainActivity **Java file**:

```
private greenBeeper g;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView b = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.linkgID);
    b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: your linear layout is still in gone mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made your `LinearLayout` as well as `ImageView` **gone** in xml. While in java you are only making your image visible and your imageView parent is still in gone state. That is the problem in your code.
Give some id to your linear layout too and make it visible when you want your imageview to be visible

Comment: SOLVED! THANKS (I was blind not to see that)

Answer (score 1):

Your `LinearLayout` is stated as `gone`.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageParent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/linkgID"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/linkg"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Try removing the `android:visibility="gone"` from the `LinearLayout`, and use the rest of you Java code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
    In your xml change visibility of LinearLayout "visible" instead of "gone" and you can see imageview in your layout.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/linkg"
            android:id="@+id/linkgID" 
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I hope you solve your problem with this..!!

Answer (score 1):

Enable both linear layout and image view visibility.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/board_out_icon"
            android:id="@+id/linkgID"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private greenBeeper g;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    ImageView b = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.linkgID);
    b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

give id to `LinearLayout` too